# Is there any documentation for pre-K&R c?

Tags: c, pdp-11

I was playing around with an online PDP11 emulator ([link](http://pdp11.aiju.de/)) and was looking at the programming section of its [FAQ](http://aiju.de/code/pdp11/programming).

It says this about programming in C on the emulator:

> You need to write pre-K&R C which is quite a bit different from modern C

I believe this is referring to the version of C in use before the publication of *The C Programming Language*. I have tried to understand this version by reading the sparse C files I can find in the emulator's filesystem, but even simple things like declaring `argc` and `argv` have eluded me. I also can't find anything about it online.

Is there any documentation, written at the time or after the fact, on "pre-K&R" C?

Comment: I think they're confused, and mean pre-ANSI C. K&R is the original C.

Comment: Is far as I rememebr no `long int` no `unsigned int` `+=` is `=+` (same other), no standard library, no preprocessor, no `#include`, no `struct` or `union`

Comment: @Barmar there was the pre K&R C.

Comment: @0___________ "No preprocessor" surprises me considering I think I saw some `#define`s in header files. Was `#define` something different back then?

Comment: Then you saw "late" C if you saw header files. Original first version of C did not support inclusion of files :) . Mike Lesk has implemented and added preprocessor I believe in 1974 or 5

Comment: @0___________ is there any documentation available on "late C"?

Comment: http://mim.update.uu.se/manuals/layered/pdp11c3.pdf

Comment: @0___________ Oooooooo!!! Update!!!

Comment: @klutt it is modern version

Comment: @0___________ I just noticed update.uu.se :)

Comment: Also in "old C", variable initialization was without `=`, so *e.g.* `int i 3;`, which is why there's that cryptic C compiler diagnostic in later versions, "Error: old fashioned initialization, use =" if you forgot the semicolon after a normal uninitialized declaration. Function argument type declarations were outside of the pre-amble, *e.g.*, `int func(a, b) int a; char b; { ... }` instead of `int func(int a, char b) { ... }`. I remember that syntax still existed  in the early 1980's when I was at Bell Labs, but I think the variable init changed earlier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this sort of question, my go-to source is the archived web page of the late Dennis Ritchie:

https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/

From there it's one click to this early reference manual for C, written by Ritchie himself:

https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/cman.pdf

This is indeed "pre-K&R C", featuring anachronisms such as `=+` instead of `+=`.

This is the same reference manual that appeared, in updated form, as Appendix A in the K&R book.

On the same page are links to several other versions of that reference manual, as well as notes about and even the source code of [two early versions of Ritchie's compiler](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/primevalC.html).  These are pretty fun to look at, although as the page notes, "You won't be able to compile them with today's compilers".

There's a whole Stack Exchange site dedicated to questions like these: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Those operators were pretty bad. Should `x=-1` be interpreted as `x=x-1` or `x=(-1)`?

Comment: @klutt Aye, there's the rub, and that's exactly why they were changed.

Answer (score 1):

Steve Summit answered about where to get the documentation. So this post is intended to summarize noticeable differences from modern C

Types for function arguments were quite different. They were not specified within the parenthesis

```
void foo(a, b)
    int a; 
    float b;
{
    // Function body
}
```

No row comments, like `//`. Only `/* */`

No logical `or` and `and`. The operators `&&` and `||` did not exist. The bitwise operators `&` and `|` were used instead.

`=-` meant the same as `-=`, which lead to ambiguity with for instance `x=-1`.

There was no `void` pointers. `char` pointers were used instead.

One could not declare variables in the for header, so one had to write:

```
int i=0; 
for(i=0; i<N; ++i)
```

`=` were only used for assignments and not initialization. Those were done like this: `int x 3;`

Implicit `int`. This is still valid in modern C. The difference is that no (sane) programmer is using it anymore. This:

```c
foo 3;
```

is actually equivalent to

```c
int foo = 3;
```

There was no `const` qualifier

Comment: With the exception of `=+` and `||`/`&&`, everything you've listed was equally true of "pre-K&R C" and actual K&R (aka pre-ANSI) C.  And of course there are no hard delineations here.  For example, the C described in the V6 reference manual had no structs at all; C as described in K&R1 had structs that couldn't be passed or assigned; but shortly thereafter the compiler was supporting struct passing and assigning just fine.