# What is ossiz in this old C compiler?

Tags: c, keyword

I was looking at one of the first compilers of c, written by dmr himself. It was written in the early 1970's, so obviously the syntax is very different. In [this](https://github.com/mortdeus/legacy-cc/blob/master/last1120c/c00.c) file, what does `ossiz` mean?

```c
ossiz 250;
```

By the way, is there any helpful article or manual on this sort of thing (older c syntax)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70407012/17635987

Comment: @kirjosieppo Added info about implicit int in and answer to that question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just like in B, it's a global variable definition with initialization. In modern C it would be:

```
int ossiz = 250;
```

Also: https://github.com/mortdeus/legacy-cc/blob/2b4aaa34d3229616c65114bb1c9d6efdc2a6898e/last1120c/c10.c#L462